# Is this the right truth table information?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[image]

I'm constructing a truth table and these are the values I put in. Am I right here or have I made any mistakes? All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in that table appears to be correct.